# Exchange 2010 sending old Out of Office message

Tags: exchange-2010, email

We are just about done with our migration from Exchange 2003 to 2010.  I have a user who has been migrated to the new system that is now out on medical leave.  He has gone into OWA and set up his Out of Office notification.  The good news is that an Out of Office message is sent, the bad news is that it appears to be sending an old outdated message from back when the user was on Exchange 2003, and not honoring the new message set up in OWA.  The user has also tried setting this up in Outlook 2010 as well with the same behavior.  I have a feeling that this is related to the old public folders (didn't they contain OOF messages?) still lingering around our Exchange org.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try opening Outlook with the switch /cleanrules

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/command-line-switches-for-outlook-2010-HP010354956.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this.  This is what fixed the issue for us.  It looks like it must have been some old or corrupt rule.

Comment: Glad this worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue following migration from Outlook 2007 to Outlook 2010.  The same fix worked from the client i.e. in RUN issue the cmd "outlook.exe /cleanrules".  The only problem was it did exactly what it said - i.e. it cleaned all rules - so I had to reset my mailbox rules.

Answer (score 0):

Have they changed *both* messages?

Exchange 2010 has the concept of Internal and External messages, and when a mailbox is moved from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010 the OOF message is copied to both the Internal and External messages.

If the user only changed one of their out of office messages but neglected the other, that would explain it. You can check the out of office message values for the user with the cmdlet `Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration username` in the Exchange Management Shell.

Comment: Yes, they have changed both external and internal.  I can see this from the output of the command you suggested.  Still the old outdated message from the exchange 2003 days gets sent instead.

Comment: Does turning the automatic replies off for the user and re-enabling them help at all? `Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration username -AutoReplyState Disabled` and then `Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration username -AutoReplyState Enabled`

Comment: Nope.  Tried that.  It seems like it's looking in a legacy spot (old PF?) for the data when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Definitely weird, but I don't believe it will be looking in the PF's because they are optional (Microsoft are also trying their hardest to get rid of them) and OOF works without them. Does setting the message using the shell make any difference at all? Also, is it just the one user, a handful of them or everyone?